# Cannot compile WiredTiger with snappy support under rhel

Tags: compiling, dependencies

I need to use `WiredTiger` command line tool for `MongoDB` data manipulation.
I got sources from `http://source.wiredtiger.com/` and ran `./configure --enable-snappy`. Got the following error

```
configure: error: --enable-snappy requires snappy.h
```

I cloned `https://github.com/google/snappy.git` into subdirectory and set `CPATH` accordingly

```
export CPATH=/home/mongod/termit/wiredtiger-2.9.2/snappy
```

Now it finds header files, but i'm getting this error

```
configure: error: --enable-snappy requires snappy library
```

Any ideas? Should I compile snappy prior to wiredtiger?

Comment: Can you just yum install `snappy` and `snappy-devel`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the snappy lib via

```
yum install snappy snappy-devel
```

If this doesn't work, you can get the sources via `rpm`.

On CentOS 7:

```
rpm -ivh http://vault.centos.org/centos/7/os/Source/SPackages/snappy-1.1.0-3.el7.src.rpm`
```

On CentOS 6:

```
rpm -ivh ftp://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/6Server/en/os/SRPMS/snappy-1.1.0-1.el6.src.rpm
```

or

```
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS/snappy-1.0.5-1.el6.src.rpm
```

then compile them.  You should do this before attempting to compile WiredTiger.